# facebook audience network error al vincular cuenta con anuncios

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook, admob

estoy tratando de implementar facebook audience network por el tema monetizar con anuncios algo asi como admob, pero tengo un problema al vincular mi cuenta con las propiedades que he creado por tema de region.

[image: Error por el tema de region banco bbva]

Yo trate de vincular una cuenta del bbva (Peru), pero me sale ese mensaje, también trate de vincular una cuenta de paypal, pero me salio error en el logueo y ahora no puedo editar mi forma de pago.

Mi duda era si para Perú no esta habilitado el tema de facebook ads,si alguien ha podido vincular alguna cuenta para que facebook pueda pagarte(que tipo de proveedor uso) y si alguien ha podido usar este servicio que es una alternativa de admob, me ayudaria muchísimo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, Facebook no trabaja con cuentas de Peru. Los contacte directamente y su respuesta fue: 
Gracias por postularse a la Red de Audiencias el dia de hoy.
En este momento no podemos aceptar su solicitud. Le agradecemos su paciencia mientras determinamos el proceso ideal para traer nuevos editores a la red.
Gracias por comunicarte con Facebook.

Comment: Creo que esto seria mas un comentario que una respuesta en si, aunque claro la pregunta tampoco es que sea de programación ...